# Getting an error while deploying my site on Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to deploy my site on Azure but I am getting this error.
Web deployment task failed. (An error occurred during execution of the database script. The error occurred between the following lines of the script: "692" and "698". The verbose log might have more information about the error. The command started with the following:"IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHisto" The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Production_Categories_CategoryID". The conflict occurred in database "NewProject", table "dbo.Categories", column 'ID'. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178587  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE.  Learn more at:

I don't know why this is happing I guess its something with migrations.

Comment: Remove the foreign key FK_Production_Categories_CategoryID,. change the table and re-create the key.